# select2 is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

My select2 is not working. It just shows up with multiple selectbox

```
<form action="">
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">

<option value="AK">Alaska</option>
<option value="HI">Hawaii</option>

<option value="CA">California</option>
<option value="NV">Nevada</option>
<option value="OR">Oregon</option>
<option value="WA">Washington</option>

<option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
<option value="CO">Colorado</option>
<option value="ID">Idaho</option>
<option value="MT">Montana</option>
<option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
<option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
<option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
<option value="UT">Utah</option>
<option value="WY">Wyoming</option>

  </select>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();
</script>
```

Error in console:
    Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.

JS FIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/y6ogss94/

Comment: You have an error in the console: `TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function` it seems select2 is not well imported.

Comment: @AnthonyB Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>

Comment: Try including `jquery` before `select2`

Comment: @AnthonyB I have used the CDN of select2

Comment: Check if sequence is correct (*jQuery and then Select2*) and jQuery is not loaded multiple times(*after Select2*)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This runs fine if you have imported correctly - jQuery library, select2 js and select2 css.

Here I have imported jquery 2.0.0 and [select2](https://select2.github.io/) css and js from their cdn and it works fine:

```js
 $(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<form action="">
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple">

<option value="AK">Alaska</option>
<option value="HI">Hawaii</option>

<option value="CA">California</option>
<option value="NV">Nevada</option>
<option value="OR">Oregon</option>
<option value="WA">Washington</option>

<option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
<option value="CO">Colorado</option>
<option value="ID">Idaho</option>
<option value="MT">Montana</option>
<option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
<option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
<option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
<option value="UT">Utah</option>
<option value="WY">Wyoming</option>

  </select>
</form>
```

**Note:** 
You need to execute your select2 initialisation code only after you have included both the js libraries and DOM has loaded, which is a general practice for most jQuery plugins, not only this. So, while using this code you should write this script after including jquery and select2 scripts:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();
});//document ready
</script>
```

Comment: You may want to use initialize select2 once DOM is loaded. So you can initialize it inside a _DOMContentLoaded_ event. The important is select2 be used after importing jquery and select2 scripts.

Comment: yeah, you're right @AnthonyB. Thanks. But I think the code snippet automatically puts all the script code inside something like "$(document).ready()" so it runs only after DOM has been loaded. I'm not sure though.

Comment: The snippet does I think, but as people will copy/paste this code to fix their Select2 problem, it could be useful to use Select2 after importing scripts and perhaps in a `$(document).ready()`

Comment: yeah thanks @AnthonyB. Just added a note for this in the answer.